# Getting top 1 record from shapefile by descending order using ArcPy SearchCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, date, sorting

I have a shapefile from the date field in it. I'm looking to get top 1 record date value by descending order.

```
readRows =    arcpy.SearchCursor(shapefile, "", "", "Last_Updated" ,"Descending")
```

Is descending order possible from ArcPy?

Comment: So-called "old-style" (non Data Access) cursors should be avoided in new code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an SQL statement to `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()`.

For example:

```py
sql_clause = (None, 'ORDER BY Last_Updated DESC')
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapefile, ['Last_Updated'], sql_clause=sql_clause) as cursor:
    row = next(cursor)
    value = row[0]  # this should get the top 1 record
```

Comment: In the question it looks like the asker is using an original rather than Data Access search cursor but I think that it's always better to use Data Access.

Comment: This does not work correctly with shapefiles and should not be the correct answer. The da.SearchCursor does not support ORDER BY with dBase tables, which is the underlying data structure for a shapefile. See the documentation at https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm 
If this worked for the author's test case, it was because the first record was already in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.  For example, a [code sample is provided in the arcpy.SearchCursor() help](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/searchcursor.htm#C_GUID-A6A0C41B-2B0B-4434-9BB7-F0BA819E4756):

```
# Open a searchcursor
#  Input: C:/Data/Counties.shp
#  Fields: NAME; STATE_NAME; POP2000
#  Sort fields: STATE_NAME A; POP2000 D
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("c:/data/counties.shp",
                          fields="NAME; STATE_NAME; POP2000",
                          sort_fields="STATE_NAME A; POP2000 D")
```

In your case try:

```
readRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(shapefile, "", "", "Last_Updated" ,"Last_Updated D")
```